# Easier way to shell out sunflower seeds

Tags: seeds, food-processing

I like the taste of sunflower seeds, however I really dislike the process of shelling them. The bags say "Eat. Spit. Be happy." But I have found that shelling it in one's mouth is not only messy, it also tends to splinter the shell and hurt gums. I have tried shelling them out by hand, but that is exceedingly time-consuming.

I know they can be purchased shell-less but I was wondering if there is some trick, as I like some of the seasoned kinds, just not a fan of the process. Any trick to unshell multiple sunflower seeds efficiently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy way where you only your teeth and your nails. The tip of the sunflower seed shell has a little bit an edge, so I bite that off and then I crack open the cut that I made with my teeth with my nails.

[image]

Comment: Nice, why didn't I think of that! You are indeed a Master when it comes to Sunflower Seed ;)

Answer (score 4):

I have to soon partake in what is known as a "sweatshop" activity in my U.S. History class in a week. I went home and timed myself for 30 minutes to see how many i can do in that amount of time. I found if you pick out two of the most hardest shells you can place them between your thumb and middle finger and use them to pinch the other seeds. By doing this you make a crack or slit in the seed and once you have done a pile of cracked seeds you can then take them and open them easier and quicker.

[image: Shelling Sunflowerseeds]

[image: Place two seeds between your thumb and middle finger]

Answer (score 3):

This method uses a resealable plastic sandwich bag, 1/2 c. sunflower seeds, water and a rolling pin.  Seal bag and roll over seeds to crack the hulls.  If you have patience you can remove the hulls by hand, or put the seeds and hulls into a bowl of water.  Skim hulls using a slotted spoon.
http://www.ehow.com/how_6148353_easy-way-shell-sunflower-seeds.html

Comment: Sounds like a great idea! Thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

You make a slit in the shell with your teeth then take it out of your mouth and then put your fingernails in the slit and open it then take the seed and eat it

Answer (score 0):

Place the seed between your two front teeth. Bite down to crack. Then, with you two fingers, push down to crack the shell again. Finally, ''lick'' the seed out with your tongue